# HBase last versions kept depending on timestamp value or real time added?

Tags: hbase

in HBase you can set a minimum versions and maximum versions to keep value.
Does that timestamp control what will be kept?

Like, if I modify the timestamp of a first row to 100, then after that, I insert a second row with the timestamp 99, and the maximum versions value is set to 1, will the first row (latest timestamp) or the second row (latest insert time) be kept?

Thank you very much for your answers.

If it doesn't keep the row with the timestamp 100, is there a database that would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp 100 row will be the top row in this case. Timestamp is not really a timestamp, you can insert anything in place of that and the row with the highest value will be treated as latest.

Answer (score 0):

It seems by manipulating timestamp you can manipulate the versions. If I understood your question correctly, if you have to exactly similar key-value-qualifier with timestamp 99 and 100. I guess latest one will be kept. In this case key-value with timestamp 100. Ill probably implement this and get back to you later!